# Testing the html elements in flask routing templates unittest

Tags: python, html, unit-testing, flask, jinja2

I have a login page for a flask app with cloud database, I want to test the results after logging in, specifically, I want to test the HTML elements after logging in. I have seen people test return status code or using `assertIn` to check if data exist.

Is there a way for me to target a specific HTML tag, like `<h1 id="userTitle"> </h1>` from rendered templates after POST username, password to the route function login()

```
    def test_users_login(self):
        result = self.app.post('/login', data=dict(username='Nicole', password='abc123'), follow_redirects=True)

        # I want to check the HTML tag's text value data after logging in
        self.assertEqual(result.data.getTag("h1", b"Nicole") #What I imagined using <h1>
        self.assertEqual(result.data.getId("user", b"Nicole") #What I imagined using id


        #This returns true which is okay, because 'Nicole' exists in the whole page
        self.assertIn(b'Nicole', result.data)
```

In my rendered jinja2 template I have this which is after logging in.

```
 <h1 id="userTitle">{{ session['username'] }},Welcome!</h1>
```

I guess assertIn works well, but I just want to know how to test an HTML tag without running a browser test.

Comment: Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into [testing Flask applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/)?

Comment: @JoshClark Yea, but it doesn't mention how to target specific HTML tag, as I want to test ````assertEqual(HTML Tag Text Value, My Value)````, to check specific HTML elements inner text. Just want to know if its possible, otherwise I have to use ```assertIn```

Comment: how about rendering template to variable (before sending to client) and use `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to work with HTML elements (like in web scraping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't get a correct answer from here, but I just managed to do the unit-test with just `assertIn`, by checking the contents of the page.
Thanks everyone